# should some unanswered "meta" questions be closed?

Tags: discussion, meta

quite a few questions on this meta branch are technically "unanswered".  some are about general information of a durable nature, but some have clearly outlived their shelf life.

is it desirable to close those questions that are no longer of interest except to a possible archaeologist?  i'm thinking, for example, of the [moderator pro tem announcement](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362/moderator-pro-tem-announcement).  many of these questions (like the present one) are tagged "discussion".

i'm not sure how closure would be accomplished with zero answers, but i think it's worth thinking about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in the nature of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions that sometimes there's no real answer, which can be accepted. Sometimes just nobody joins the discussion. So regarding [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), I think we can live with "unanswered questions". Here the main site features cannot be applied the same, I think. Closing means nobody would be able to join discussion later.

You're right, it's important to be able to see unanswered questions, especially regarding the tags

- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- [support](/questions/tagged/support)
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Here I agree with you, it would be beneficial if we close questions which cannot be answered, so we can see better the remaining real unanswered questions. We can vote to close similar to the main site choosing a meaningful reason. For example, the obsolete mod pro tem announcement could be closed as "not a real question" today.

However, I guess often it's more preferable to change the tag to [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) instead of closing if we notice the tag [support](/questions/tagged/support) doesn't match the question, for example.

Answer (score 6):

I think it could make sense to close them as "too localized". Your example question fits the description that it "is unlikely to ever help any future visitors". Moreover, if I'm not mistaken, closure would prevent the question from being bumped from time to time.

Comment: too bad i can't accept more than one answer -- both are good; but stefan's illuminates more facets of the problem, so i accepted that one.